# Filter a list of files by values in an xarray, where file names contain padded numbers

Tags: python, glob

I have a long list (.ca 3000 elements) of filenames in this format:

```
'path/00001_type.png'
```

The IDs of each file are zero padded and go up to 1000 (i.e 01000_type.png) and type can take 3 values (circle, oval, cube).

And an xarray, exclude, whose values identify the files I want to *exclude* from the list in that format. To reference these values I have used:

```
exclude  = exclude.values
exclude = [5, 8, 10, 20,..., 204]
```

**The goal**

Produce a list which contains no files with IDs in the exclude list, for all types:

```
files = 
['path/00001_type.png','path/00002_type.png','path/00003_type.png','path/00004_type.png','path/00006_type.png','path/00007_type.png','path/0000_type.png','path/00009_type.png', 'path/00011_type.png']
```

I have tried using the regex and glob modules to select the files, but I cannot figure out the correct way to search through the list, accounting for padding and the rest of the file path.

I also wonder if there's a more efficient way to do it than this.

**example of what I've tried**

```
files = []
for file in filenames:
    for ID not in exclude:
        if file.glob("*{:05d}_type.png".format(ID)) in item_list2[1]:
             files.append(e) 
files
```

Comment: what is item_list2 ? also what is "for ID not in exclude" supposed to do?

Comment: item_list2 was meant to be filenames, that's just a temporary variable I made to try and work on this myself. "for ID not in exclude" hopefully would grab the files in "filenames" (a list) which do not have that zero-padded ID.

Answer (score 3):

Using Regex.

**Demo:**

```
import re
import os

filenames = ['path/00001_type.png','path/00002_type.png','path/00003_type.png','path/00004_type.png', 'path/00005_type.png', 'path/00006_type.png','path/00007_type.png','path/00008_type.png','path/00009_type.png', 'path/00011_type.png']
exclude = [5, 8]
files = []

for file in filenames:
    m = re.search(r"(\d+)", os.path.basename(file))    #Get Int from file name
    if m:
        if int(m.group(1)) not in exclude:  #Check in exclude list
            files.append(file)
print(files)
```

**Output:**

```
['path/00001_type.png',
 'path/00002_type.png',
 'path/00003_type.png',
 'path/00004_type.png',
 'path/00006_type.png',
 'path/00007_type.png',
 'path/00009_type.png',
 'path/00011_type.png']
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I think it's because my path has a lot of numbers in it ? The true path is : /home/home02/mm18lhf/.fastai/data/Nx256_s200000.0_N500study_N2000train/train/

Comment: Try using `os.path.basename` Updated snippet